# Why do I see users with hundreds of badges?

Tags: discussion, badges

I spend most of my Stack Exchange time on Stack Overflow, and I often see users with upwards of 200+ badges just in bronze. Though when I look at the badges on their profile page and look at the available, at the very most I can only spot maybe 50 bronze badges.

Do badges carry over from site to site, meaning those badges were accumulated through other sites also, or are all of these badges acquired from tags?

Comment: No, badges don't carry over from site to site.

Comment: Some badges are awarded multiple times which could be the reason that you see 50 bronze badges but total count could be 200+ bronze badges.

Comment: Because therapy for SO addiction is still an evolving art.

Answer (score 25):

Some badges can be awarded multiple times. If you look at [my badges here for example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/161198/bart?tab=badges) you will see several bronze badges. But not the 104 I have now. That is because I by now have received 60 nice answer badges, as indicated by the "x 60" behind the badge.

[image]

So yes, users do have that many badges, but they are not all individually shown.

Comment: This post  could bring you to 61 "Nice Answer"s.

Comment: By which point I should probably propose to rename it to the "you've wasted far too much time here" badge.

Comment: @Bart, that badge already exists: http://stackoverflow.com/badges/83

Comment: @GamecatisToonKrijthe Luckily I don't have that.....oh...wait. :S

Comment: @juergend - Status completed :)

Comment: There's also the TAG badges that can be awarded: http://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags

Comment: @SchmitzIT I am wilfully ignoring your comment and will not attempt to get them all.......ah who am I kidding.

Comment: @Bart - It's stronger than you! Give into the urge! ;-)

Comment: It's all fun and games until someone gets the `homework` badge.