# What is the full count of badges?

Tags: discussion, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I see users with hundreds of badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157553/why-do-i-see-users-with-hundreds-of-badges)

On this page https://stackoverflow.com/badges are 80 badges. But I see that this user https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9 (for example)has 900 (!!) badges. What's the full count of badges ?